# WPF Adorner Overlay Problem

Tags: wpf, adorner

I am trying to achieve functionality similar to that of a Popup, without using a Popup, but instead adorning my ContentControl with a basic adorner.  Basically, I want the ContentControl to have an "overlay" effect, whereby it is the topmost object, above all other elements - similiar to that of the Popup control.

Here is the problem that I am running into, and I am hoping that someone can point out where I am going wrong:

I have a stand grid with two row definitions.  The first row contains a UI element - for example, a rectangle.  The second row contains a custom control that I have developed to emulate the functionality of a "drawer" sliding out.  Basically, when I click on button, I am going to animate a TranslateTransform to "slide" my ContentControl "up".  This works fine - except that it gets cropped underneath the rectange in the first row of the grid.  If I remove the row definitions in the grid, then when the desired behavior is achieved - the ContentControl is moved "up" and partially "on top" of the rectangle.  The rectangle is merely a place holder for what I am trying to achieve.  I basically want to have a drawer type control that can slide out and be on top of all other controls.

I am somewhat new to using the Adorner class, so, I am hoping that someone can please point out where I am going wrong.

Thanks.

Chris

Comment: can you elborate on why you cant use Popup for this?

Comment: Sure.  Let's say that I want to create the appearance of a drawer sliding up from the bottom of the window.  If I use a popup, as soon as I set IsOpen to true, the content becomes visible, as it doesn't respect the boundaries of the window, so, it will no longer look like something is sliding up from the bottom of the window.

Comment: What if you set the height of the popup to zero and animate it to full size? you set a fixed height on the layout Panel in the popup so that it doesnt resize, but instead clips with the popup. worth a shot atleast :)

Answer (score 0):

Change the parent of the adorner to the full grid, and not just your control.  If you put a control in a grid row, and set the adorner to adorn the control, it will usually be clipped to that row because the control is.